# Include Statement inside jina2 that use a Variable for the included filename

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to do this:

```
{% for a in as %}
{% include "{(a}}.jinja"%}
{% endfor %}
```

But i am getting an Error, that `{a}.jinja` is Not found.
So it seems that it does Not substitude the Variable. Why? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inside the `{%%}` Block, i Can use variables directly. This Works:

```
{% include a + ".jinja" %}
```